# How do I create Thumbnails for Shared links

Tags: thumbnails

When I try to link my website on the Shared feature no thumbnails show up. What do I need to do so that Facebook will generate those thumbnails?

Comment: Facebook probably generates those by rendering your website in some sort of virtual browser. Is there anything on your site that might confuse such a thing? (Flash intro?)

Comment: Not that I can think of....it's a pretty simple, straight forward program called Web Studio.....drag and drop type stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Your thumbnail must be at least 50x50 pixels, and you must specify it with a special meta tag in your site's HTML.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yersite.com/yerimage.png"/>
```